# Cycle Power Contol

Tags: power

I am trying to create my own neon animation controller using raspberry pi. These are already for sale here: http://prosites-llcwccd.homestead.com/SPELLERS.html . But I want to make my own controller so that I can play with different settings without having to buy an individual unit for each function.

Basically I need to make a controller that can cycle power to 120V plugs with speed and on/off variables.

Can anyone direct me to a tutorial for building a cycle controller with 115V outputs?

Comment: you want to know how to control an light using an RPI? ... i think that it has been done many times and a quick search on the web should turn up something.

Comment: I want to control an electrical outlet. This is a high voltage application. I've looked online, but could not locate a tutorial for 115V output controls.

Comment: google `microcontroller control power outlet`

Comment: this would be easiest to use .... https://www.amazon.com/Phoneix-SSR-25DA-Module-24-380VAC-Supplies/dp/B07D3L5Y7X

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot! Any recommendation for search terms on the programming for cycling the power?